# Trouble condensing code in C++ - SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

*This is probably going to sound like a stupid question...*

I have this piece of code in C++, that uses the SFML library:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

void textDisplay(sf::Text& display_text, std::string display_str, sf::Font display_font, int char_size) {
    display_text.setString(display_str);
    display_text.setFont(display_font);
    display_text.setCharacterSize(char_size);
    display_text.setStyle(sf::Text::Regular);
}

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "Game");
    sf::Font arial;
    if (!arial.loadFromFile("fonts/arial/arial.ttf")) {
        return 0;
    }

    sf::Text text;
    textDisplay(text, "Hello, World!", arial, 30);

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f, 10);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Because I'm going to repeat the same four lines of code over and over when I'm trying to display the text onto an SFML screen, rather than repeating the code, I created a function (`textDisplay`) that takes in four arguments (the `Text` object itself, a string, a font, and the character size) and initializes the `Text` object for me.

For some reason, the text doesn't display - is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Some stuff:

- The window is called `window`.
- There's no error when compiled, so I have no idea where the error is.
- The board itself is just black, there's no text on `window`.

If the error has to do with the function itself, can you recommend an alternative to typing the same four lines over and over again?

Comment: Do you flip/present the buffer after drawing?

Comment: @IvanRubinson Yeah, I did - hang on, I'll put it in the snippet.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Yup, got it.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint after you initialize the text and check if it's properly initialized in a debugger?

Comment: @IvanRubinson Ummm... how do I do that?

Comment: Where do you init arial?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Treycos In the first `init` code block thing. Do you want the whole code?

Comment: @IvanRubinson Code::Blocks.

Comment: Yup, this code may help, also, if you don't choose any color for your text it might be rendered black on... black.

Comment: @Treycos Without a color specification though, it shows white for the text. Put the code in.

Comment: Woops, sorry ^^

Comment: Just curious to everyone, is this a stupid quesiton?

Comment: Absolutly not !

Comment: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: That does not help @Ivan Rubinson, he said there was no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, you were setting your text with a temporary font, since its a normal variable and not a reference/pointer:

```
void textDisplay(sf::Text& display_text, std::string display_str, sf::Font& display_font, int char_size) { //Just make it a reference and its done! :)
    display_text.setString(display_str);
    display_text.setFont(display_font);
    display_text.setCharacterSize(char_size);
    display_text.setStyle(sf::Text::Regular);
}
```